# Communication with a VMWare guest system without network

Tags: api, vmware, vmware-player

does anybody know an API that allows to send and receive data to/from a VMWare guest system without using an IP network?

I have to communicate with a program inside a VMWare guest but the guest is not allowed to have an IP network. As file transfers into the VM via Drag&Drop are possible I assume that there is an API - I just need to know if this API is open to 3rd party programmers or if it is only available fro the VMWare Player itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there is a solution for my problem:

**Virtual Serial Port**

VM-Ware allows to create virtual serial ports for the guest that are connected on host side to a named pipe.

I therefore created two helper programs, one on host side which listens on a TCP port and a specific named pipe and transfers all the incoming data between them.

A second helper program runs in the guest VM and does the same between the serial port and the TCP port I want to access.

The only draw-back is that the serial speed is limited to 128kBit/sec. May be that can be increased by using multiple virtual serial ports...

**Virtual Machine Communication Interface (VMCI)**

Using [VMCI](http://pubs.vmware.com/vmci-sdk/) there is an API for creating a shared memory region that is accessible from both hast and guest system.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can access those with the [VIX API](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/).

More specificely, the Drag&Drop is implemented with following functions:

- [VixVM_CopyFileFromGuestToHost](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/vix112_reference/lang/c/functions/VixVM_CopyFileFromGuestToHost.html)
- [VixVM_CopyFileFromHostoGuest](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/vix112_reference/lang/c/functions/VixVM_CopyFileFromHostToGuest.html)

Basically all `VixVM` functions may be relevant for your tasks. They are all documented in the [official VIX API reference](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/vix112_reference/index2.html).

Comment: Thanks for the interesting links. However by browsing the API documentation I could verify that there is no direct API that could be used for my purpose.